# 'of' keyword and string output

Tags: f#

I'm just getting into F# and I'm confused about some syntax and the results.

I have this type:

```fs
type ApplicationId = ApplicationId of System.Guid
```

Which atm should be some sort of an alias for a Guid, as far as I understood it. The thing is when I do this

```fs
let application = ApplicationId(System.Guid.NewGuid())
System.Console.WriteLine(application.ToString())
```

it prints me this

```
ApplicationId 7902aa4a-b262-48d9-8d05-ad1e2ed5f7e2
```

while I was expecting just the Guid value. What kind of construction is this really cause the 3 entries in the language ref on `of` don't seem to be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a [type alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-abbreviations) for `System.Guid`, then try this:

```ml
type ApplicationId = System.Guid

let application : ApplicationId = System.Guid.NewGuid()
System.Console.WriteLine(application.ToString())
```

Your `ApplicationId` type is a [discriminated union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions) that wraps the `System.Guid` type, but is not an alias for it. That's why your original console output indicates that you've got a GUID value wrapped inside an `ApplicationId`.

Comment: The lack of | was misleading here. Also found that I can unwrap the actual Guid with an unwrapping function 'let unwrapApplicationId (ApplicationId id) = id'

Comment: Yeah, that first | is optional, which can definitely be confusing.